# Fetch all entries with dateUpdated after a given time

Tags: entries, datetime

I'm trying to grab all Entries that were updated after a given date and time.

It seems like I can grab all entries updated after a *date* using the following:

```
{% set timeLimit = now | date_modify("-2 min") %}
{% set updated = craft.entries({ dateUpdated: '>=' ~ timeLimit }).section('myChannel') %}
```

The problem is, that code doesn't actually seem to take time into account at all, just date. `timeLimit` in the above will always return something like `2014-08-21`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You concatenate the strings `'>='` and what is output from the `timeLimit` var (the same as `{{ timeLimit }}` does). So it gets concatenated to `'>=2014-08-22'`.

You need to change two things. First add a space after the comparison operator and second, change the date output to include the time by using the [`date`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/date.html) filter. I suggest to use  `'c'` as the value for the formatting parameter, as it returns the datetime ISO 8601 formatted.

```
{% set timeLimit = now|date_modify('-2 min') %}

{# Get entries with `dateUpdated('>= 2014-08-22T01:55:00+02:00')` #}
{% set updated = craft.entries.dateUpdated('>= ' ~ timeLimit|date('c')) %}
```