# Get count of new entries since last visit

Tags: entries, count

I'm relatively new to craft, but thanks to this board I am making great progress :-) But here is my first question, which is not answered in here:

I would like to get the count of entries of a certain section, which have been published **since the last visit of a user**. I'm pretty sure I have to somehow use a cookie for this, but am completely unaware of how to do this in combination with twig :(

Comment: Are you talking about logged in users?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear about this. I mean normal, frontend visitors without any account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [cookies](https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-cookies) Plugin (or [for Craft 2](https://github.com/lewisjenkins/craft-lj-cookies))  to store the value of the timestamp when the users has visited the page for the last time. Or you can create your custom code like explained in the question: [How to set a cookie](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/648/prescribed-way-to-set-cookies-from-plugin-or-twig)

You can get the current timestamp like it's stated in the [docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/datetime#see-also)

```
{% set currentTimestamp = now|date('U') %}
```

And store the cookie like [explained](https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-cookies#setting-cookies)

```
{# Set the cookie using 'set' variable #}
{% do craft.cookies.set( NAME, VALUE, DURATION, PATH, DOMAIN, SECURE, HTTPONLY) %}
{% set yourTimeStamp = getCookie( NAME ) %}
```

Then you'll search for entries [after the specific date](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2083/fetch-all-entries-with-dateupdated-after-a-given-time)

```
{% set newEntries = craft.entries.postDate('>= ' ~ yourTimeStamp)|length %}
```